# Read PRI Files in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I have a [PRI file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) with some string resources. I want to read and display it in .NET.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Would you please describe what a PRI file is, perhaps link to official/vendor documentation or similar? According to lack of activity on your question, SO community does not know what you are asking (including myself).

Comment: The link you provided already have sample code. What specific question do you have?

Comment: @Ray No, it doesn't have any code to read **compiled** PRI files.

Comment: @User: you better find out for sure. Narrowing down the scope usually helps solving the problem. I am a certified Windows developer and I never heard about such extension.